# How to run a Python Facial Recognition Project using OpenCV on Spyder

Tags: python, opencv

I'm an OpenCV newbie and have a Python project that I have been trying to run on Spyder. what I can't figure out, however, is that inspite of having added the OpenCV package, I am receiving an error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'.

any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You have to add all the modules before running the code.
Add module cv2 using 'pip install cv2'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you donot have to build opencv from source.Decide on the opencv distribution(opencv/opencv-contrib) and then use the link below to figure out the installation of the same.If you are not building it from source the following link will help you out:
https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/#description

Answer (score -1):

The error message clearly states that you don't have module named 'cv2'.

So, try installing the Module using "**pip install cv2**" from the command line.